# Specifying lifetimes in function pointer types in a struct

Tags: rust, function-pointers, lifetime

I have a function `foo` defined as follows:

```
fn foo<'a>(a: &'a i32, b: &i32) -> &'a i32 { a }
```

I want to store  a pointer to that function in a struct:

```
struct S {
    f: fn(a: &i32, b: &i32) -> &i32,
}
```

Because there are two input lifetimes, the result lifetime cannot be inferred:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  |
2 |     f: fn(a: &i32, b: &i32) -> &i32,
  |                                ^ expected lifetime parameter
  |
  = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value,
    but the signature does not say whether it is borrowed from a or b
```

When I ask the compiler for `foo`'s type, it's not very helpful either:

```
let () = foo;
```

gives me

```
expected type `fn(&'a i32, &i32) -> &'a i32 {foo}`
```

which obviously doesn't work because `'a` is not defined anywhere.

So how do I declare a lifetime in this context? Trying one of

```
f: fn<'a>(a: &'a i32, b: &i32) -> &'a i32
f<'a>: fn(a: &'a i32, b: &i32) -> &'a i32
```

results in a syntax error, and I could not find documentation covering this specific situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the lifetimes on the struct:

```
fn foo<'a>(a: &'a i32, b: &i32) -> &'a i32 { a }

struct S<'b, 'c> {
    f: fn(a: &'b i32, b: &'c i32) -> &'b i32,
}

fn main() {
    S {
        f: foo,
    };
}
```

Note that you cannot elide the second lifetime in this context.

> But that would mean that a call to `(s.f)(&x, &y)` would not be generic over the lifetimes of `a` and `b` anymore, unlike `foo(&x, &y)`

Then you want [*higher-rank trait bounds* (HRTBs)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html):

```
fn foo<'a>(a: &'a i32, _b: &i32) -> &'a i32 { a }

struct S<F>
    where for <'b, 'c> F: Fn(&'b i32, &'c i32) -> &'b i32,
{
    f: F,
}

fn main() {
    S {
        f: foo,
    };
}
```

Comment: But that would mean that a call to `(s.f)(&x, &y)` would not be generic over the lifetimes of `a` and `b` anymore, unlike `foo(&x, &y)`.

Comment: Great! I didn't know about HRTBs.

Comment: It's worth to mention that hrtb syntax works with function pointer types as in `f: for<'a,'b> fn(a: &'a i32, b: &'b i32) -> &'a i32`.